# Convert nested array to json in PHP without additional coding

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to convert my array to a Json String and use it for send message using Firebase Cloud Messaging Server.
My array is :

```
$data = array(
                "to" => "cMbucIFcJMA:APA91bH_Wq0sPrMhTmhJ9gPJX7GUsRo...",
                "notification" => 
                    array(
                        "body" => "sadeq",
                        "title" => "test notification"
                    )
                );
```

and when I use `json_encode($data)` my back String is:
`{"to":"cMbucIFcJMA:APA91bH_Wq0sPr.... \n","notification":"Array"}`
how can I convert this array to valid Json without have `Array` in my notification String???

My completely function is:

```
public function SendFromPost(){


                $data = array(
                    "to" => "cMbucIFcJMA:APA91bH_..... ",
                     "notification" => 
                    array(
                        "body" => "sadeq",
                        "title" => "test notification"
                    )
                );






                  $ch = curl_init();
                  curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_URL , "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
                  curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_POST , 1);
                  curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS , $data );
                  curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , true);

                      $headers = [
                        'Content-Type: application/json \n',
                        'Authorization: key=AIzaS.......'
                      ];

                  curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER , $headers);

                  $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
                  curl_close($ch);


                 return var_dump(json_encode($data));

            }
```

My code is correct. but I don't know why my php do like this.

Comment: json encode is recursive, that's not you issue.  Wnat's a `back String`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I just want to true json back

Comment: show all your code please : as per @mkaatman answer, works for me.  Should also work for you.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Completely function added.

Comment: Remove `var_dump`... https://3v4l.org/tdrDA

Answer (score 1):

Your code works. You've got an extra `;` that isn't valid after your nested array.

```
<?php
$data = array(
                    "to" => "cMbucIFcJMA:APA91bH_Wq0sPrMhTmhJ9gPJX7GUsRo...",
                    "notification" => 
                        array(
                            "body" => "sadeq",
                            "title" => "test notification"
                        )
                    );

var_dump(json_encode($data));
```

**Yields**

```
string(115) "{"to":"cMbucIFcJMA:APA91bH_Wq0sPrMhTmhJ9gPJX7GUsRo...","notification":{"body":"sadeq","title":"test notification"}}"
```

Comment: This is just a typo and I correct it. but my problem is not resolved

Comment: What version of PHP? Try it here to see if it's your environment or your code: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b17ac66d03ce25babff121ea88be60343a036c06

Comment: My php version is: 5.5.38

Comment: That PHP sandbox links only goes up to 5.5.34 but it works there. Unless there was a specific regression in .38 something else in your environment is going on. The code is correct.